# Third party API integration - How to structure the database

Tags: database, api, google-calendar-api, integration, google-contacts-api

In my app I am integrating different third party APIs, like Google Contacts, Google Calendar, Mailchimp, etc...
Each third party API has specific settings I can ask to the user to apply during the sync with my app.

I have two options:

1. I make unique table like "integration" where I store all connections. Here I am afraid I will need to add many columns to track settings for different APIs (contact privacy, calendar id, Mailchimp audience id...etc...)
2. I make a table for each third party API integrated in order to track separately all relevant setting through dedicated columns. Here I may have many tables when I reach many different third party APIs.

I would think the second is the best, but I need your help to structure my database as per best practices to be scalable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is clearly against Google's Terms of Service, specifically [Section 5 e. Prohibitions on Content](https://developers.google.com/terms#e_prohibitions_on_content):

> Unless expressly permitted by the content owner or by applicable law, you will not, and will not permit your end users or others acting on your behalf to, do the following with content returned from the APIs:
>
> 1. Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or keep cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;
> 2. [...]

And there are very good legal and moral reasons for that. So the answer is actually not to do it and use the APIs every time.

Comment: Uhm, sorry but I think the above is different argument. I am talking about storing user's connection settings, not data, otherwise how can I allow user to keep the connection live at any login? Data I am storing is token and settings like (sync the Calendar name "John" instead of another. The document you shown it related to content like storing event from Google Calendar into my app. And I don't make this. By the way, if I want to sync user's Google Contacts and connect them to my app tasks, do I need to store at least Google Contact id, can I?

Comment: @Echecivuole Oh, sorry then. I was under the impression that you were saving user data directly (you only talk about saving connections, which are not IDs). Could you edit your post to make it clear? :)

Comment: no worries! I have edited the post to avoid misunderstanding. Btw, the point which is still open is: when I allow user to sync his contacts in my app, can I store contacts data into my db, after user allowed, to speedup the showing of those contact? otherwise for each request I should call API.